# How to wrap an interface in an object while exporting it in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a file called x.ts, here is what it holds:

```
interface x {
  x: string;
}
interface y{
  x: string;
}
interface z {
  x: string;
}
interface i{
  x: string;
}
```

I want to export the interfaces like this:

```
export = {
   a: {
      x,
      y
   },
   b: {
      z,
      i
   }
}
```

How can I do this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Objects** (every value in JavaScript / TypeScript) **can contain only values** as properties (methods, constants, properties) which interfaces are not. But don't worry, there's the way! Its name is **namespaces**.

```
export namespace a {
   export interface x {
      x: string;
   }
   export interface y{
      x: string;
   }
}

export namespace b {
    export interface z {
       x: string;
    }
    export interface i{
       x: string;
    }
}
```

See [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) for more info.

#### Secondly

I recommend using **ECMAScript modules**, not CommonJS. If you use a normal TypeScript compiler, TypeScript automatically compiles to Node.js modules. You used it in the import but not in the export. **Don't use `export = {}`**. See [TypeScript Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) for more.

In tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // ...
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "commonjs"
    }
}
```

And then `import {a, b} from "./x.ts"`